# Why is my left margin slightly larger than my right margin

Tags: luatex, margins, geometry

I've noticed that my left margin is slightly larger than my right margin while making a document. Here's an MWE of what I'm describing:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[
  showframe,
  marginparwidth=0cm,
  marginparsep=0cm,
  margin=0.75in]{geometry}

  \begin{document}
  \begin{center}
    \Huge lallalalalalal\\
  \end{center}
\end{document}
```

And here's an image of the rendered PDF output:

[image]

Is there any way to make the left and right margins perfectly equal? I'm using LuaLaTeX.

Comment: I don't see the difference with your MWE, compiled with pdflatex from texlive2016.

Comment: Your margin length settings can be combined into a single `margin=0.75in`.

Comment: Remember to pass also the paper format, probably you want `paper=letter`.

Comment: @samcarter I used lualatex to compile this document which has this problem. You're right, pdflatex displays the document properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue affects the geometry package when used with the LuaLaTeX engine.
Based on browsing the [mailing lists](http://tug.org/pipermail/luatex/2016-May/005906.html), the geometry package has not been updated to work with the latest versions of LuaTeX.

The fix is to add a `\RequirePackage{luatex85}` to the preamble of the document, which fixes the margins and gives the expected output.