# Left margin larger than right

Tags: margins

My left margin is greater than my right.
I've not made any explicit changes to margin sizing. I'm compiling with Texmaker to PDF. 
I'm using the following packages.

```
\documentclass [MS] {uclathes}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\counterwithout*{footnote}{chapter}
```

The only mention of leftmargin in the `.cls`  is here:

```
% VERSE
%   The verse environment is defined by making clever use of the
%   list environment's parameters.  The user types \\ to end a line.
%   This is implemented by \let'in \\ equal \@centercr.
%
\def\verse{\let\\=\@centercr  
  \list{}{\itemsep\z@ \itemindent -1.5em\listparindent \itemindent 
          \rightmargin\leftmargin\advance\leftmargin 1.5em}\item[]}
\let\endverse\endlist

% QUOTATION
%   Fills lines
%   Indents paragraph
%   
\def\quotation{\list{}{\listparindent 1.5em
    \itemindent\listparindent
    \rightmargin\leftmargin\parsep 0pt plus 1pt}\item[]}
\let\endquotation=\endlist

% QUOTE -- same as quotation except no paragraph indentation,
%
\def\quote{\list{}{\rightmargin\leftmargin}\item[]}
\let\endquote=\endlist

% DESCRIPTION 
%
%  To change the formatting of the label, you must redefine 
%  \descriptionlabel.  

\def\descriptionlabel#1{\hspace\labelsep \bfseries #1}
\def\description{\list{}{\labelwidth\z@ \itemindent-\leftmargin
       \let\makelabel\descriptionlabel}}

\let\enddescription\endlist

\newdimen\descriptionmargin
\descriptionmargin=3em
```

[The source of UCLAthes is found here](https://github.com/uclathes/uclathes/blob/master/uclathes.cls)

I do not have any BCOR. Is there somewhere else binding correction would occur?

I've reviewed these questions, but to no avail.
[Why is my left margin slightly larger than my right margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354801/why-is-my-left-margin-slightly-larger-than-my-right-margin)
[Left margin wider than right one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183995/left-margin-wider-than-right-one)

Edit; even after adding:

```
\usepackage[pass,letterpaper]{geometry}
```

The result is still unchanged

[image]

Comment: Please give us a link to your used class `uclathes` ... Do you use doublesided printing with binding correction? Then the inner margin is binding correction + inner margin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\leftmargin` is not connected with the page dimensions: it is a parameter pertaining to lists.

The class sets

```latex
\textwidth=6.5in
\textheight=9in
\oddsidemargin=0.0pt
\evensidemargin=0.0pt
```

Since US letter paper is 8.5in wide and 11in high, this means a margin of 1in on each side. The class *doesn't* set the paper width and height, so the default A4 paper wins (this is the default of all standard TeX distributions, unless explicitly set to another paper size).

If you add `\usepackage[pass,letterpaper]{geometry}`, you get something like

[image]

where the margins are equal.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not resolve the issue. I have edited the question accordingly. Thank you

Comment: Incidentally, adding \textwidth=6.5in
\textheight=9in
\oddsidemargin=0.0pt
\evensidemargin=0.0pt explicitly fixed it